# Disable Refresh with reactjs

Tags: javascript

anybody knows how to disable refresh.  the following does not seem to work.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => { 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: You can't, and this is not specific to React in any way.

Comment: You can't prevent the user from refreshing, nor should you really be trying. You should go back to why you need this solution, what's the root problem here?

Comment: the root problem is to prevent users from leaving the page during a voice call session.

Comment: You can't stop a user from refreshing / navigating, that's there choice.  But what you could do is store your voice session state, and then when the page is reloaded, use this to get them back to were they were.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing you can do (with respect to you wanting to prevent a user from accidentally leaving the voice call) is to show them a message they have to confirm before they leave. Try this:

`window.onbeforeunload = ()=>"If you leave this page, you'll also leave the call";`

Maybe you can also do that in the addListener syntax you already tried (simply return a string instead of false and change onunload to onbeforeunload).

Answer (score -1):

This is done in the components class by the   shouldComponentUpdate   function, and in use effect by the input parameter, although it can be controlled by rect.memo and pure component and use callback and use memo